# Create Xen guest with preinstalled packages and settings

Tags: debian, scripting, xen

For context, I'm creating a script to simplify the process of creating xen guests. The script uses `xen-create-image` and uses a bunch of flags to set as many useful settings as possible (distro, vg, root-disk size, IP, etc). This is all on a Debian 10.

I want to know if there's an other Xen tool or configuration I can use to (pre)install certain packages, and set certain settings/configuration files in the newly created guest.

I want to avoid using an image file with all the preinstalled packages and then `dd` into the new LV, and then have to change hostnames, IP, etc.

Is there such a command or setting?

**EDIT:**
For clarification, I'm using open source Xen 4.11

**EDIT 2:**
I have considered SSH, but apparently xen-create-image does not install and enable openssh-server.

Comment: Would an answer using Ansible or another similar orchestration toolset be acceptable or must the answer involve a solution provided directly by xenserver?

Comment: @kemotep I'd like to currently avoid orchestration toolsets as I'm currently creating an "infrastructure" from scratch. But if there's no better way, Puppet (Community edition) is the demanded tool to use. Best part is, I have no idea how to manage a Puppet server.

Comment: Okay, just to confirm: Are you using the open source version of Xen or Citrix XenServer? Please let us know the version. If you are not aware of the differences: the open source version of Xen is overall nearly identical to Citrix's version. Citrix XenServer has new features and functions that is later added to open source Xen. And Xen lacks the enterprise support contracts of course. Not too different from how Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS's relationship works.

Comment: @kemotep I'm using open source Xen 4.11. I've edited the question clarifying that.

Comment: I've discovered the `--roles` option, which appears to be very close to what I want. Gonna play with that tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

xen-create-image has an option called `--role`; these roles are defined as `sh` scripts in `/etc/xen-tools/role.d/`, and you can create your own, as long as it is executable.

I made a really simple role, just for testing:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

prefix=$1

installDebianPackage ${prefix} openssh-server

chroot ${prefix} /bin/systemctl enable ssh
chroot ${prefix} /bin/echo 'PermitRootLogin yes' >> ${prefix}/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

`prefix=$1` is by default a folder in `/tmp/` with a randomly generated name. In here `xen-create-image` builds the file system and installs packages before putting it in the logical volume or image (or so it seems).

`common.sh` is a script containing a bunch of functions that `xen-create-image` uses to build the VM.
`installDebianPackage` is one of those functions, as far as I can read, and this installs packages specified into the VM.

Lines starting with `chroot` could be commands making sure certain settings are set, adding lines into configuration files and so on. This is a powerful feature of roles, as this makes it possible to run basically any command. `systemctl start`, `systemctl stop`, and `systemctl restart` of course don't work, but `systemctl enable` does.

In the case of enabling, `sshd` took about 5 minutes to start after starting the machine, including the boot time and my machine somehow saying "can't process the volume group" 50 times before actually booting.